# I wanted to check whether one of the input value is same any of others

Tags: jquery, input, controls

I wanted to check whether one of the input value is same any of others.

my html code :

```
<input name="p1[]" class="player"><span class="result"></span><br>
<input name="p1[]" class="player"><span class="result"></span><br>
<input name="p1[]" class="player"><span class="result"></span><br>
<input name="p1[]" class="player"><span class="result"></span><br>
<input name="p1[]" class="player"><span class="result"></span><br>

<button id="control">Control</button>
```

I use jquery. I can input values control whether empty

jquery code

```
$(function(){

 $('#control').click(function(){
   $(".player").each(function(index){

     if ($(this).val() == "" || $(this).val() == " "){
        $(this).next('span').html("Null");
     }

   });
 });
});
```

Comment: All `.player` class has value `null`. What's the issue??

Comment: @JensonMJohn This null value control . I want same input "value" control

Comment: How is the jquery code fragment related to what you are trying to do? What have you tried and what is your problem?

Comment: @MarkusBruckner Thank you for your interest. Velimir Tchatchevsky has solved my problem.

Comment: @vulkan Oops, forgot to reload the page before submitting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your function to check if any of your inputs have the same value:

```
var values = [];
$(".player").each(function(index){
    ...
     if ($.inArray($(this).val(), values) === -1){
        values.push($(this).val());
     }else{
        alert("This value already exists");
     }
});

   });
```